# Emacs lisp - how to try/catch handle an error?

Tags: emacs, error-handling, elisp

In the following **defun**...

```
(defun re-backward-match-group (rexp &optional n)
  "Grab the previous matches of regexp and return the contents of
  the n match group (first group match if no n arg is specified)"
  (save-excursion
  (unless n
    (setq n 1))
  (when (numberp n)
    (when (re-search-backward-lax-whitespace rexp)
      (when  (= (+ 2 (* n 2)) (length (match-data)))
        (match-string-no-properties n))))))
```

If no match is found, an error is thrown by `re-search-backward-lax-whitespace`

How would I catch that error and return nil or `""` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re-search-backward-lax-whitespace` has an optional `noerror` argument.

```
(re-search-backward-lax-whitespace rexp nil t)
```

will not signal an error.

For more general error handling, you can use `ignore-errors` or `condition-case`. For information on the latter, see

[Error Handling in Emacs Lisp](http://curiousprogrammer.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/error-handling-in-emacs-lisp/)